# Test Data Generation: How to automate? [Excel -> SQL]

Tags: sql, database, excel, vba, testing

I want to automate my test data generation and hoped for some approaches.

My current situation: I have two excel sheets with **static** data (`patients` and `doctors`) and some with **dynamic** data [for example `weight records` for an active patient, weight records for an inactive patient, etc.] (these values are not static, because it should be different for every patient and I want to see trends and dependencies). But what I want is to create INSERT INTO Statements out of this. It needs to be considered that for every patient a dynamic sheet must be calculated and that there is a foreign key relation.

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: I'm using `SAP HANA` as database.

Best regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it you want? to be able to do this regularly, or a one off?  What DB are you taking the data to?

Comment: It would be okay if it works one time or manually with justifiable efforts, but it would be great if it could be done regulary (maybe automatically).

I'm using SAP HANA as database.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav : So I think I am open to any possible solution.